# Google Chrome blocks "Ctrl+(letter)" and "Alt+(arrow)" shortcuts when in text field

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, gnome3, ubuntu-18.04

Google Chrome blocks shortcuts of the form <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+(letter) 
(e.g., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close the current tab) as well as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+(arrow) when I'm in a text field in the current tab. This includes the address bar and being unable to open another tab with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> when entering an address. This might be intended behavior since a recent update, but I couldn't find an according release note.

**Is there an option to deactivate this "feature"?** I couldn't find anything in `about://flags` so far.

---

If relevant, I'm running Chrome 71.0.3578.80 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 18.04 (Gnome 3) with Kernel 4.15.0-42.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Could you give an example of a website on which this happens.

Comment: Happens on every website and even on a new tab (or any tab) when in the address bar. As I can't find anything on this even though it's been this way for a week makes me think it could be something in Gnome intercepting the `Ctrl` presses...

Comment: Does it happen in Incognito mode?

Comment: Yes, it happens in Incognito mode and/or all plugins disabled.

Comment: Do you mean Ctrl+(any letter) or Ctrl+(anything)?

Comment: Strange. Perhaps uninstalling Chrome, cleaning folders, and re-installing might help.

Comment: @Scott I was thinking of (any letter). I'm now noticing that `Alt`+`<-` also does not work.

Comment: OK; please [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks, but I tried that already without success. I did `apt purge` on chrome and removed `~/.config/google-chrome` and `~/.cache/google-chrome`.

Comment: Might be a conflict with some other installed product.

Comment: This is happening to me, too, using Chromium Version 71.0.3578.80 on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: This started happening to me after upgrading to chrome 71.

Comment: Upgrading to version 73.0.3664.3 (by switching to the google-chrome-unstable package) has fixed this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by removing the German keyboard layout (I had US English and German before) and then re-adding (standard) German layout.

I had noticed before that the blocking only occured when in German layout, not in English. That might have been a coincidence, but removing and re-adding the "problematic" layout helped.

Comment: Aha, thank you! This helped me as well -- it looks like the problem only happens for me in "English (intl., with AltGr dead keys)", not "English (US, alt. intl.)"

Answer (score 0):

The update to Chrome 72 today solved the issue.

Related bug on the chromium bug tracker: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=899881

> Comment 43 by tejaskal...@gmail.com, Jan 31 (3 days ago)
>
> I can confirm this is fixed on :
>
> Google Chrome 72.0.3626.81 (Official Build) (64-bit)
>   Revision    ac8b982e05014492d1bd7d317628a4f22a97ffa0-refs/branch-> heads/3626@{#796}
>
> OS    Linux
>
> JavaScript    V8 7.2.502.24
>
> Thanks!

Related fixing commit: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/faa579def265753007f87c3ea85a907f0ed469b0